# how to override QState and use it

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to override QState functions onEntry and onExist by its child class . How would I call the constructor of the QState. I'm so confused about reimplementing the QState .

```
class s : public QState
{
public:
    s(QState *parent = 0);
    ~s();
protected:
    void onEntry(QEvent *event) override;
    void onExit(QEvent *event);

};
void s::onEntry(QEvent *event)
{
    qDebug("on enter");
}

void s::onExit(QEvent *event)
{

}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    s * state = new s();
}
```

and QState is like:

```
class QState
{
protected:
     .
     .
public:
     void onEntry(QEvent *event);
     void onEntry(QEvent *event)
};
```

Comment: does class **QState** have function **onEntry **and **onExist**?

Comment: yes, according to the documentation http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstate.html

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: @bipll thanks for your reply, I don't know how to override the qstate and use it. can you show me an example code.

Comment: Your post contains an example, eh? `class s`, it is derived from QState. You then use it when building the machine instead of vanilla QState.

Comment: I don't know how to use it, what to pass the constructor, should I pass a QStatemachine variable ?

Comment: @andreahmed, what do you want your `class s` to do? You are already overriding the functions in your code above.

Comment: @InnocentBystander I'm not sure how to call the class s, I'm confused about the constructor

Comment: @andreahmed, please explain what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'm trying to have a state machine that stays onEnter() forever until a condition happen inside the onEnter(), then i move to the next state by saying addtransition